# Shell script - connecting to Heroku database while running on (different) Heroku dyno?

Tags: postgresql, shell, heroku

I currently have a production PostgreSQL database running on a separate Heroku dyno.

I'd like to deploy a simple shell script on a different dyno (for a number of reasons), that among other things, will reset the database every 2 weeks.

I've tried using both the `heroku` and `psql` commands to connect to my database in my script, but unfortunately I get the following errors:

```
$ heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL
bash: heroku: command not found
```

Which makes sense because the Heroku toolbelt isn't installed on a heroku dyno.

And then:

```
$ psql -h DATABASE_HOST -p
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package
```

Unfortunately, you can't do a simple `apt-get install postgresql-client` because Heroku prevents you from being able to install packages. (You'll get the following error):

```
~ $ apt-get install postgresql-client
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Is there any workaround for this? I know I could write a python script and use a pip module to connect to the database, but I'd rather this be a shell script to build off an existing one.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly: 

you are running PostgreSQL inside a normal Heroku dyno, and you don't use the Heroku PostgreSQL addon? 

Since Heroku does rotate all dynos every 24 hours, this will delete your data.